# Memory usage REGEX

Tags: regex, awk

Could you help me to modify the following one-liner to get more precise memory usage - right now it's just an integer I would like to include first value after coma.

```
free -m | awk '/Mem:/ {tot = $2;} /cache:/{printf "%d\n", $3 / tot * 100}'
```

Thank you

Comment: `printf "%.1f\n"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `%d` format specifier is forcing printf to print an integer value. If you change it to `%f` then it would print the full number. You can use `%.nf` to limit the number of decimal places printed so `%.1f` would print one decimal place.

Comment: Already posted above, although with less explanations  ^_^

Comment: @ripat Should have made it an answer :). If the correct answer is in a comment, then it's fair game to be "reposted" as an answer, since an OP cannot mark a comment as "accepted".

Comment: @MDMarra. I agree. My apologies but the answer was so short and obvious...

Comment: @ripat: obvious to you and I because we know the answer but clearly not obvious to everyone. As you can see, answers don't have to be short either, I think longer is better.